# ManyToMany Relation → Add a value to the junction table

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I have two entities: Component and Attribute. Components can have multiple Attributes and Attributes can also have multiple Components. The value of the attribute will be stored in the junction table "ComponentAttribute". I don't know whats the best way to add the value.

```
public class Component
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(ComponentAttribute))]
    public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Attribute
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(ComponentAttribute))]
    public List<Component> components { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ComponentAttribute
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Component))]
    public int componentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Attribute))]
    public int attributeId { get; set; }
}
```

```
Attribute attribute = new Attribute();
Attribute attribute2 = new Attribute();
Component component = new Component();

component.attributes.Add(attribute);
component.attributes.Add(attribute2);

this.dbConnection.Insert(attribute);
this.dbConnection.Insert(attribute2);
this.dbConnection.Insert(component);
this.dbConnection.UpdateWithChildren(component);

// After this I have to load the new ComponentAttributes and add the value manual
```

So it would be nice, if someone could give me a hint how to access the value

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately, you cannot do this.**

SQLite-Net-Extensions uses `InsertAll` method inside Many-To-Many relationships handler and inserting only that properties which marked as `ForeignKey` into database table.

Best workaround is that you using in question.
Load `ComponentAttributes` entity from database by known data (`Attribute.id` and `Component.id`) and then update `value` of recieved `ComponentAttribute` object by primary key (`ComponentAttribute.id`).